# Group_by hosts variable

Tags: ansible

How to shorten this code so that there is no repetition when I group by hosts? Instead of repeating rhel5, rhel6 and rhel7 blocks. I have tried with_items but no luck?

```
---
- hosts: "{{hosts}}"
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=rhel{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}    
- hosts: rhel5
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ansible_distribution}} {{ansible_distribution_release}} {{ansible_distribution_version}}"

- hosts: rhel6
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ansible_distribution}} {{ansible_distribution_release}} {{ansible_distribution_version}}"

- hosts: rhel7
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ansible_distribution}} {{ansible_distribution_release}} {{ansible_distribution_version}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [patterns](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html#patterns):

```
---
- hosts: "{{hosts}}"
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - group_by: key=rhel{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}    

- hosts: rhel5:rhel6:rhel7
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ansible_distribution}} {{ansible_distribution_release}} {{ansible_distribution_version}}"
```

If you need all but something, you can use:

```
- hosts: rhel*:!rhel4
```